# How to connect to specific instance behind Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying my app via Elastic Beanstalk, which creates and Elastic load balancer and puts all my instances behind it (3 or more).

Is there a way to contact each of these instances directly? I want to trigger a specific command on each instances (`git pull` command to synchronize with the latest code in my remote repo).

I have the list of IP address and public DNS of the instances from `PHP SDK` but since the firewalls rules restricts the source of IP address to the elastic load balancer IP on port 80, I can't seem to access them directly.

Is there a way around it?

P.S. The SSH port seems to open for all traffic, but how can I create a trigger with that? I'm hoping to create a PHP script to automate this with a webhook on the remote repo.

Answer (score 3):

I highly suggest you use the [EB CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-getting-started.html#eb3-cli-git) with git integration for all deployments, no matter how small. It is great because you can map a git branch to an environment with `eb use YOUR_ENV` then when you run `eb deploy` with that branch checked out it will deploy to that environment.

There is a lot of work involved in ensuring multiple servers pull the correct code and everything is working as expected. What if a server is in the processes of spinning up but is not ready for SSH so your script skips it and it does not get the new code?

Also, what happens when a new server spins up but it is using the old application because that's what is in EB? You could have your kickstart do a git pull but then what happens when you are not ready to push, a new server starts and is alone with the new code?

I could probably find 5 more edge cases without breaking a sweat. Look into `eb deploy`, you will be happy you did.

Comment: Hi, can this be done with AWS php sdk? I'm asking because this thing is running on a client's machine and needs to performed from a page in the admin area

Comment: This runs from command line, there might be an SDK tool but I doubt it. You could trigger this from php with something like `exec()`. The servers that runs this should have an isolated code base so you can pull from git then deploy. It will look something like `exec("cd /path/to/code && git pull && eb deploy")`. I question the use case for the client deploying from a web based tool and suggest engineers handle it but you probably have your reasons.

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup a CI (or make a simple web service) and create a webhook in your repository. Your CI need to get all instances under your Elastic Beanstalk environment and then call `git pull` via SSH.

Or, just create a cron job in your all instances via `.ebxensions` script.

I thought it's not a good practice in Elastic Beanstalk to run `git pull` in order to synchronize your app with your git repo. Because, it misused the *Application Version* semantic meaning. Sometimes, you can't determine which app version are in your instances from *Application Version*. It's better to create a new *Application Version* in Elastic Beanstalk to deploy a new app version.

If you host your repo in Github, you can take a look into [CodeDeploy](http://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/).

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer.. I will try to dig more into the CI and SSH.. with regards to CodeDeploy I too thought of that, but then I read on amazon blog that "CodeDeploy is targeted at customers who manage their EC2 instances directly, instead of those who use an application management service like AWS Elastic Beanstalk". I'm actually using AWS Elastic Beanstalk and it does not say what you're supposed to use when using beanstalk (i can definitely upload new application versions but that's too much hassle for minor fixes like a line of code here or there, simple bug fixes) [1] goo.gl/nEVcwU

Comment: "i can definitely upload new application versions but that's too much hassle for minor fixes" - but that *is* a new version of your application, so that's how you should do it. If you don't want to do that, then you should probably not use Beanstalk or CodeDeploy. Instead do deploys manually, and push updates over SSH using Fabric or something similar.